# Using Wildcards in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WildCardNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<EvenNumber> le = new ArrayList<>();
        List<? extends NaturalNumber> ln = le;
        ln.add(new NaturalNumber(50));//  *   Compile time error
        ln.add(new EvenNumber(46));   // **   Compile time error 
    }

}

class NaturalNumber {

    private int n;

    public NaturalNumber(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

}

class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber {

    public EvenNumber(int n) {
        super(n);
    }

}
```

While studying Wildcards in Oracle docs, I found the aforementioned code.

According to the source the variable "ln" can not accept any "NaturalNumber"s, since it is a list of "EvenNumber" contents. I tried adding a "EvenNumber" object to it. That is also not being accepted.

It seems the variable "ln" is a read only object as mentioned in the doc. Could you guys please explain as to why this object is read-only ?( I am able to add null values though) If we are not able to add "NaturalNumber"s, why can't we add "EvenNumber"s too ? Since according to Wildcard we have specified, that the variable "ln" can accept subtypes of "NaturalNumber", and "EvenNumber" being the subtype?

Answer (score 5):

This is a classical problem. The reason it's fobidden is because if it was allowed:

```
    List<EvenNumber> le = new ArrayList<>();
    List<? extends NaturalNumber> ln = le;
    ln.add(new NaturalNumber(50));
    ln.add(new EvenNumber(46));  
    EvenNumber even = le.get(0); // ClassCastException
```

We are guaranteed by le declaration that all numbers must be even numbers. But if you're allowed to add a NaturalNumber there then this guarantee breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Type safety checks are based on the *declared* type of the object involved.  This declaration

```
List<? extends NaturalNumber> ln = le;
```

describes a (reference to an) object `ln` whose type parameter is **not precisely known** at compile time and in fact could be different at different points during the execution of the program.  Assigning to that variable a reference to an object whose type is more precisely known doesn't matter, because (1) that doesn't change the declared type of `ln`, and (2) because a differently-parameterized list could be reassigned later.  (That that does not actually occur in the given code is irrelevant.)

In fact, you cannot add any element to list `ln`, because you (explicitly) do not know what type of elements it accepts.  You can, however, *retrieve* elements from it:

```
le.add(new EvenNumber(0));
NaturalNumber n = ln.get(0);
```

You have the reverse situation if you specify a lower bound:

```
List<? super EvenNumber> lq = le;
NaturalNumber n = lq.get(0);      /* type safety error */
```

The situation is exactly reversed: you cannot be sure what types of objects are in list `lq`, as it could be a reference to, say, a `List<Object>` (though you can always do this:

```
Object o = lq.get(0);
```

.)  You can, however, be certain that whatever the actual type parameter, it is consistent with *adding* `EvenNumber`s:

```
lq.add(new EvenNumber(12));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't add to ln because that could potentially result in a runtime error. C# and Scala better accommodate what is known as covariance/contravariance where the generic parameter is always used as a output/input parameter. C#/Scala will let you safely down/up cast accordingly. Collections and lists use the generic parameter in both an input and output capacity, so you can't safely allow casting, and as a result those types are invariant even in C#/Scala.